# How to compute the exterior derivatives of differential forms after changing the frame

Tags: differential-geometry

Consider a smooth surface $(\Sigma \subset R^{3}, \phi)$, where $\phi(x,y):\,  D\subset R^{2} \mapsto R^{3}$ is a parametrization of $\Sigma$, $D$ is a open set in $R^{2}$.

As we know that at every point $(x,y, \phi(x,y))$ on $\Sigma$ which has a tangent space spanned by $\lbrace \phi_{x}, \, \phi_{y} \rbrace$ and the dual basis $\lbrace dx, \, dy \rbrace$. Then, when we are considering a $1-$ form on $\Sigma$ having a parametrization $\omega=a(x,y)dx+b(x,y)dy$, we have
$$d\omega=(b_{x}-a_{y})dx \wedge dy.$$
Now the question is:

If $\omega=c(x,y)e_{1}+d(x,y)e_{2}$, where $e_{1}, e_{2}$ are the orthogonal frame after using gram schmidt orthogonalization. How can I compute $d\omega$ in this frame?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don't use $e_i$ for differential forms. You should write an orthonormal basis for the tangent space as $\{e_1,e_2\}$ and let $\omega_1,\omega_2$ be the dual basis for the cotangent space. The connection form $\omega_{12}$ is uniquely determined by the structure equations
$$d\omega_1=\omega_{12}\wedge\omega_2 \quad\text{and}\quad d\omega_2=-\omega_{12}\wedge\omega_1.$$
Then, if $\phi = f\omega_1+g\omega_2$, you differentiate, as usual, getting
\begin{align*}
d\phi &= df\wedge\omega_1 + f(\omega_{12}\wedge\omega_2) + dg\wedge\omega_2 + g(-\omega_{12}\wedge\omega_1 \\ &= (df-g\omega_{12})\wedge\omega_1 + (dg+f\omega_{12})\wedge\omega_2.
\end{align*}
To calculate the connection form, of course, you need to know the induced metric on your surface and actually compute the coframe $\omega_1,\omega_2$ explicitly. (Many times it is better to find an orthogonal parametrization, rather than a graph parametrization. Of course, sometimes that's hard to do in practice.)

Comment: Please, could you explain why we have the terms $f(\omega_{12} \wedge \omega_{2})$, and $g(-\omega_{12} \wedge \omega_{1})$? when we differentiate.

Comment: I got it now. Could I have one more questions?, in practice, in order to find the connection form $\omega_{12}$ from the equation $d\omega_{1}=\omega_{12} \wedge \omega_{2}$ and $d\omega_{2}=-\omega_{12}\wedge \omega_{1}$, we still need to express $\omega_{1}, \omega_{2}$ in terms of $dx, dy$, right? I mean we need to compute $d\omega_{1}$.

Comment: Yes. Sure. You need some coordinates with respect to which to do the calculation. I'm just suggesting that you often want to parametrize the surface differently (e.g., surfaces of revolution).